# Run window - parsing multiple params to CMD window

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, runtime

Pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> gives the *run* window, just so there's no confusion as to what I'm referencing. I want to parse several arguments to a CMD window, like the following:

```
cmd /k start chrome.exe
```

This would just start `chrome.exe`.

But instead of restarting another instance of CMD, I would like to parse more commands within this same window. How could I include several commands with their respective arguments on one line?  I'm not sure how the concatenation works for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute multiple commands by using the `&`sign.

For example:

```
cd /d "C:\temp" & myprogram.exe
```

The above will first navigate to c:\temp, then start myprogram.exe from that location.

Alternatively, you can create a .cmd file and simply write all the instructions on new lines.

For example, mycmd.cmd will looks like:

```
cd /d "C:\temp" 
myprogram.exe
```

This does the exact same thing as the program above.

Assuming the mycmd.cmd is located in c:\, you can then do <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `c:\mycmd.cmd` to start your program. If you place mycmd.cmd in a folder that is in your %path% environmental variable, such as c:\windows\system32, you do not even need to include the location and just `mycmd.cmd` will work.

Comment: Feel free to mark this answer as answered if it answered your question to let others know you no longer need help.